# Upload image to Cloudinary IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsdata

I can't upload images to Cloudinary hosting via HTTPS POST request, I want to use the simple API methods instead of the SDK. I'm having a problem with formatting the image in a byte array buffer or as Base64 encoded.

Here's my code:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSString *strImageData = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/MYSECTER/image/upload"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
NSString *strRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file=%@&upload_preset=MYSECTER", strImageData];
request.HTTPBody = [strRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    NSDictionary *recievedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    NSLog(@"RECEIVED: %@", recievedData);

}] resume];
```

Unfortunately I receive the following answer from the server: "Unsupported source URL..."

I really tried a lot of other methods, but I can't get it to work.

**UPDATE:** When I put URL link at 'file' param all works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, and it works very good:

```
// image for sending
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

// Dictionary that holds post parameters. You can set your post parameters that your server accepts or programmed to accept.
NSMutableDictionary* _params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[_params setObject:@"SECKET_PRESET" forKey:@"upload_preset"];

// the boundary string : a random string, that will not repeat in post data, to separate post data fields.
NSString *BoundaryConstant = @"----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy";

// string constant for the post parameter 'file'. My server uses this name: `file`. Your's may differ
NSString* FileParamConstant = @"file";

// the server url to which the image (or the media) is uploaded. Use your server url here
NSURL* requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/SECKET_KEY/image/upload"];

// create request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// set Content-Type in HTTP header
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", BoundaryConstant];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

// post body
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// add params (all params are strings)
for (NSString *param in _params) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [_params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

// add image data
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
if (imageData) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n", FileParamConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// set the content-length
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[body length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

// set URL
[request setURL:requestURL];

[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    NSDictionary *recievedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    NSLog(@"RECEIVED: %@", recievedData);

}] resume];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with the Cloudinary API but I hope this is helpful. I had a look at the docs on '[Uploading with a direct call to the API](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#uploading_with_a_direct_call_to_the_api)'.

I think you are required to provide the 'file' and 'upload_preset' as POST parameters (not concatenated as data in the body).

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSString *strImageData = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/MYSECTER/image/upload"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

// Replace this:

//NSString *strRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file=%@&upload_preset=MYSECTER", strImageData];
//request.HTTPBody = [strRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// With this:

NSString *imageDataStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:imageData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setValue:imageDataStr forHTTPHeaderField:@"file"];
[request setValue:@"MYSECTER" forHTTPHeaderField:@"upload_preset"];


[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    NSDictionary *recievedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    NSLog(@"RECEIVED: %@", recievedData);

}] resume];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time, but it doesn't work.    
I received error message: "Missing required parameter - file";

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cloudinary's SDK in order to perform an upload image task as explained here: http://cloudinary.com/blog/direct_upload_made_easy_from_browser_or_mobile_app_to_the_cloud

> The following code samples show a direct unsigned upload API call in Objective-C for iOS...:

```
CLCloudinary *cloudinary = [[CLCloudinary alloc] init];
[cloudinary.config setValue:@"demo" forKey:@"cloud_name"];

NSString *imageFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"logo" 
ofType:@"png"];

CLUploader* uploader = [[CLUploader alloc] init:cloudinary delegate:self];
[uploader unsignedUpload:imageFilePath uploadPreset:@"zcudy0uz" options:@{}];
```

> The following code samples show a more advanced example: specifying a custom public ID of user_sample_image_1002, making it possible to later access the uploaded image, and assigning a tag to simplify management of the images. In addition, we show an example of building a dynamic URL that performs an on-the-fly image manipulation: generating a 150x100 face-detection-based thumbnail of the uploaded images for embedding in your application.

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imageFilePath];

[uploader unsignedUpload:imageData uploadPreset:@"zcudy0uz" options:
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"user_sample_image_1002", 
@"public_id", @"tags", @"ios_upload", nil] withCompletion:^(NSDictionary 
*successResult, NSString *errorResult, NSInteger code, id context) {

    if (successResult) {

      NSString* publicId = [successResult valueForKey:@"public_id"];
      NSLog(@"Upload success. Public ID=%@, Full result=%@", publicId, 
      successResult);
      CLTransformation *transformation = [CLTransformation transformation];
      [transformation setWidthWithInt: 150];
      [transformation setHeightWithInt: 100];
      [transformation setCrop: @"fill"];
      [transformation setGravity:@"face"];

      NSLog(@"Result: %@", [cloudinary url:publicId 
      options:@{@"transformation": 
      transformation, @"format": @"jpg"}]);                

     } else {

         NSLog(@"Upload error: %@, %d", errorResult, code);            

      }

 }   andProgress:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, NSInteger totalBytesWritten, 
     NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToWrite, id context) {
     NSLog(@"Upload progress: %d/%d (+%d)", totalBytesWritten, 
     totalBytesExpectedToWrite, bytesWritten);
 }];
```